# Why is this script doing nothing after the for loop?

Tags: bash, docker, for-loop, docker-compose, sh

I have this bash script. It uses cqlsh to wait for a cassandra schema to be set up. The arguments to the script are the cassandra db keyspaces. Essentially it is checking that there is at least 1 entry in the `schema_updates` table. This table records all database migrations. If there is any entry in this table, it means that the keyspace that table is now available.

The issue is that none of the commands after the for loop are being executed when I use this script as a docker-compose entrypoint. It works fine if I just call it up directly.

I don't think the problem has anything to do with cassandra or the cassandra query. I have tested each line individually, I have run the the whole script on my local, I have gone into the container started up by the docker-compose file to start the script manually and it works exactly as expected in all three cases.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

 for keyspace in "$@";
 do
      KEYSPACEFOUND=1
      until [[ $KEYSPACEFOUND = 0 ]];
      do
          cqlsh -u cassuser -p casspwd cassandra -e "select filename from $keyspace.schema_updates limit 1" 2>/dev/null | grep "(1 rows)" >/dev/null 2>&1
          let KEYSPACEFOUND=$?

      done
 done
 echo "All keyspaces are available"
 exec ./bin/applicationStartScript
```

Comment: Add `echo`s everywhere and see what is happening.  Add `set -x` on the beginning of the script and inspect the output. Simplify the whole `KEYSPACEFOUND` assignment with just `until cqlsh .... | grep -q '(1 rows)'; do :; done`

Comment: Maybe this is a race condition? Something isn't available at the execution of the script?

Comment: OK, I added `set -x` and I noticed that `KEYSPACEFOUND` was never being assigned to `0`. I did your refactoring and it seems to still be happening -  the exit code is never `0`.

Comment: Actually, the `set -x` did work. I realise that one of the arguments I was passing was actually not a valid keyspace. The for loop was getting stuck on it. What should I do here? Should I post an answer? I think it was just a silly mistake on my part,  not sure how much others can gain from this

Comment: I think its fine to put answer to your own question so the community will know the problem has been resolved and they will not look into your question, save time of others :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that one of the arguments I was passing to the script was not a valid keyspace. This meant that the `until` loop would never terminate and therefore neither would the for loop.